# C: Error Expected a ')' while passing the strings to a function

Tags: c

I am compiling a small C program with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.  Here's a small snippet:

```
void test(char[] s)
{
  //some code here
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Expected a ')'

How would I resolve this issue?

Actually the full code is  here , [which implement radix sort MSD in C (chapter 10 of this book)](http://www.packtpub.com/opencl-parallel-programming-development-cookbook/book):

```
#define N // integers to be sorted with values from 0 -256 

void MSD (char[] s) {
    msd_sort(s, 0, len(s), 0)
}

msd_sort(char [][] s, int lhs, int rhs, int d )
{
    if (rhs<=lhs+1) return; 

    int * count =(int * )malloc(257*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        count[s[i][d]+1]++;
    for(int k = 1; k < 256; ++k)
        count[k] += count[k-1];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        temp[count[s[i][d]]++] = a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    s[i] = temp[i];
    for(int i = 0; i<255;++i)
        msd_sort(s, 1 + count[i], 1 + count[i+1], d+1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void test(char s[]) {}
                ^^---brackets go here
```

What you wrote is Java.

Also :

- don't forget to give a value to your `#define N`.
- I see one `malloc` and no `free`, that's a memory leak.

Comment: Mmh, my answer stands. All brackets go to the right of the identifier (multiple brackets included)

Comment: In the C language, the brackets go after the variable names, like this: `char s[]`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Then I would say this is an error in the book.

Comment: @user3891236 if it's written exactly as-is, then yes. Books are no more perfect than humans.

Comment: @user3891236 Highly probable. Throw the book away and get yourself a copy of "Kernighan & Ritchie: The C Programming Language". Be sure to get the second (ANSI) edition.